# Connection Pool with Python and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I want to create and use a connection pool for an app I'm making. I'm trying to figure out if I need to close the connection pool itself when exiting the app or not. I know how to and when to close the connections to the connection pool. I can't seem to find an answer as to whether I need to close the connection pool itself, or how to do it for that matter. The actual connection to SQL, not the connections to the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, no worries! Just [grab SQLAlchemy's Connection Pools](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#module-sqlalchemy.pool) and go to town.

Really, though, unless you're doing this for exercise and are willing to think through all of the corner cases (and as you can tell from the length of that manual page, they're not few), don't implement connection pooling yourself.